# Entity Framework OfType() dynamically

Tags: c#, entity, oftype

How can you do:

```
Type ty = Type.GetType("Student");
var students = db.People.OfType(ty);
```

in a way that will work?

Why?

I only used people/students as an example, Here's a slightly more detailed explanation of why I might want to do this.

I wish to be able be able to store postal address information in a relational structure that pertains to a particular culture. My idea was to have a base type : "Address" and inherited types of it, eg: "UK_Address". Then my "People" entities would just have an "Address" reference. I would store the name of the specific address type as a string within the Person type, and use this name to dictate the behaviour of the program when interacting with addresses.

If that makes sense!? :s

Comment: What are you triing to do with this? If you try to make a difference between inherited classes, than there is better way to do that in EF.

Comment: I've edited the original post ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your looking for an answer along the lines of:

```
Type ty = ...
var students = db.People.OfType<ty>(); //Doesn't work, see below
```

Then I don't think it will work without reflection. See

[IQueryable OfType<T> where T is a runtime Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669760/iqueryable-oftypet-where-t-is-a-runtime-type)

Comment: .ofType<ty> is realy not working. it can be compiled. the "IsSubclassOf" is not exists.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, I said .ofType<ty> wouldn't work without reflection, and Type.IsSubclassOf does exist. It's actualy the converse of IsAssignableFrom: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx

Comment: Sorry - I miss "IsSubclassOf" in .NET 4. However - the "IsSubclassOf" is working only for classes. No structs or interfaces. The "OfType<ty>()" is realy bad approach. There is way with reflection to do that, but realy complex and inefficient. Better to not advice non-functional or semi-functional solutions.

Comment: Ah thanks, I also missed that c.IsSubclassOf(ty) also returns false if c and the ty represent the same class. IsAssignableFrom  is better.

Answer (score -1):

```
Type ty = typeof(Student); // tyopeof() is "safer" than Type.GetType()
var students = db.People.Where(x=>ty.IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType()));
```

Comment: OfType is translatable to SQL. EF supports inheritance that way.