# Generic method to count occurances of a given SubClass in a List and why the Type parameter is not found

Tags: c#, generics

I have a `List<Doctor> doctors` where `Doctor` is an `abstract` class.

In the list I have SubClasses such as `DoctorJunior`, `DoctorSenior` etc.

How can I count the number of occurrences of a particular SubClass.

This works `int count = doctors.Count(c => c is DoctorJunior);`

however when I place it in a method using `Type` as a parameter it does not work.

```
public int GetOccurences(Type doctorType)
{
    // return Passengers.OfType<doctorType>().Count();

    // return doctors.Count(c => c is doctorType)

    int count = 0;
    foreach (Doctor doc in Doctors)
    {
        if (doc is doctorType)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The parameter `doctorType` cannot be found.

Why is the parameter `doctorType` not found and how can I make a generic method to count types?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IQueryable OfType<T> where T is a runtime Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669760/iqueryable-oftypet-where-t-is-a-runtime-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is that `is` operator is used only when you compare instance of type with type itself. You can use `doc.GetType()` instead and compare this type with type that is stored in `doctorType` :

```
public int GetOccurences(Type doctorType)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (Doctor doc in Doctors)
        if (doc.GetType() == doctorType) count++;

    return count;
}
```

Or use LINQ :

```
public int GetOccurences(Type doctorType)
{
    return Doctors.Count(d => d.GetType() == doctorType);
}
```

You can even use `Convert.ChangeType(obj, type);` to count however it's not recommended :

```
    static int GetOccurences(IEnumerable<object> collection, Type t)
    {
        return collection.Count(item => { try { Convert.ChangeType(item, t); return true; } catch { return false; } });
    }
```

Or Generic approach :

```
    static int GetOccurences<T>(IEnumerable<object> collection)
    {
        return collection.Count(item => item is T);
    }
```

P.S.

It worth noting that your custom class such as `DoctorJunior` is type (defined by You) but *not* a `System.Type`.

System.Type is a class that works with types.

A. Correct

```
if(c is DoctorJunior) ...
```

- We use `is` operator here with class instance on the left side and class name on the right (not instance of class `System.Type`)

B. Incorrect

```
Type t = typeof(DoctorJunior);
if(c is t) ...
```

- We attempt to compare *instance of class* with instance of `System.Type` using `is` operator. This is not valid since `is` operator doesn't work this way. It only allows to compare instance of class on left side and type name on right for example  `if(myVariable is Int32 / string / MyClass / ...)`

Comment: Why does this work `doctors.Count(c => c is DoctorJunior)` it does not call `getType()` and uses `is` Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a generic method, whereby generic constraints could give you some additional type safety (constrain the type argument to subclasses of `Doctor`)

```
public int GetOccurences<TDoctor>() where TDoctor:Doctor 
{
    ...
    if (doc is TDoctor)
    ...
}
```

Incidentally, this works well with your both your commented out lines

```
return Passengers.OfType<TDoctor>().Count();
// or
return doctors.Count(c => c is TDoctor);
```

---

or stick with what you've got and use `GetType()` (but there is no type safety, I could easily pass `typeof(int)`, for example)

```
public int GetOccurences(Type doctorType)
{
    ...
    if (doc.GetType() == doctorType)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Operator `is` doesn't expect variable of type `System.Type` on the right side. So, you get an exception. Valid using of `is` operator in your case only can be something like `doc is DoctorJunior`

To make your method work, you can use following code:

```
public int GetOccurences(Type doctorType)
{
    return doctors.Count(c => c.GetType() == doctorType);
}
```